# Automatically add comments to minimized YouTube window using Chrome Extension (MV3)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome extension that needs to automatically add comments to a YouTube video. The extension works by opening a new window and navigating to the YouTube URL. Here's how I open the window:

```
await chrome.windows.create({
    url,
    focused: false,
    type: "panel",
    state: 'minimized'
});
```

After that, I attempt to scroll down to the comment section and insert a comment using JavaScript like so:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.style.zoom = '0.25';
    document.querySelector('[section-identifier="comment-item-section"]').scrollIntoView();
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById('placeholder-area').click();
        setTimeout(() => {
            dispatchPaste(document.querySelector('ytd-commentbox #contenteditable-root'), comment_data);
            setTimeout(() => {
                document.getElementsByClassName('yt-spec-button-shape-next yt-spec-button-shape-next--filled yt-spec-button-shape-next--call-to-action')[0].click();
            }, 1000);
        }, 1000);
    }, 1000);
}, 3000);
```

The issue is that the comment section doesn't seem to load unless the window is focused or maximized manually by the user.

Things I've tried:

Zooming out and scrolling to the bottom programmatically, thinking that the comments section needs to be in the viewport.
Programmatically firing focus events to emulate user interaction.
Using `document.hidden` and `document.visibilityState` to manipulate visibility.

None of these have worked so far.

Comment: Seems like you're asking about how to violate Youtube's terms of service.

Comment: Check how the site detects its visibility state, then spoof it in [page context](/a/9517879). The likely reason is their use of requestAnimationFrame, which runs only in visible pages, so try overwriting it with setImmediate or setTimeout.

Comment: @Ouroborus Not at all. I am doing this for educational purposes only and nothing else.

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried to add before code, but nothing happened: `window.requestAnimationFrame = function (callback) {return setTimeout(callback, 0);};`

Comment: As mentioned in my comment you need to do it in [page context](/a/9517879).